# Impact of deleting/moving a folder in svn repo on svn dump and load

Tags: svn, svnadmin

I have a folder A in svn-repo with multiple projects in it. Now i want to move some of the projects from this folder to another folder B. I use the svn move command to accomplish this.
Now the folder A is not needed in the repository. So i want to delete it and i use svn delete to accomplish this. My question is once i delete folder A will this delete revision impact in anyway for the dump and load process? This is required since we are planning to take a dump of whole repo and migrate it onto another server. My question is depicted as below,

```
/
-FolderA
   -A
   -B
   -C
-FolderB
   -D
   -E
   -F
```

My question is,

```
/
-FolderA

-FolderB
    -A
    -B
    -C
    -D
    -E
    -F
```

And delete FolderA.

I hope i have raised my question in understanble manner. I want to know the impact of this deletion during dump and load process.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete the folder A. This will not cause any issue in the dump you are gonna take and you can load this dump to any other repo without any issue. When you are deleting something from SVN, you are just removing it from the current state of SVN. Any time you can go back and see the older revisions.